# API callback not getting called with FireStore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have following method which i call, but i dont see any call back getting called.

```
 Log.d(TAG,"adding to firebase");
        // Create a new user with a first and last name
        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("first", "rambo");
        user.put("last", "Lovelace");
        user.put("born", 1815);


db.collection("aks")
                .add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Log.d(FIRE_TAG, "akshay:DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(FIRE_TAG, "akshay:Error adding document", e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCanceled() {
                        Log.w(FIRE_TAG,"akshayoncancel listner");
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                        Log.w(FIRE_TAG,"on completed listner");
                    }
                });
```

Log.d(TAG,"done");

I see that "adding to firebase" and "done" printed on console, but nothing success/failure callbacks are not getting called. Why so?

Comment: does `.collection("aks")` exist?

Comment: Do you have internet connection on the device?

Comment: I was testing on emulator, it works on actual device. Does firstorstore not work on emulator?